# How to save HTML file after redirecting the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, domdocument

I am trying to save a HTML page after redirecting to a new url. The redirection works fine but it seems after redirecting nothing else works in my php script.

I am using CURL to pretend running from a browser where I get the 302 error to redirect to the page. All I need is to save the HTML page content automatically after redirecting.

Any advices are welcome.

```
$new_url =  'www.example.com';
$path = 'C:/page.html';

// redirect to new pages
header('Location:'. $new_url);
exit();

// load and save the file
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($new_url);
$doc->saveHTMLFile($path);
```

Comment: Have you tried redirecting after writing the page to file?

Comment: Since I am using CURL to view the page, I will be directed to a page with 'The document has moved here' 302 message and from there i need to redirect to the main HTML page. So by saving before redirection I will be just saving the 302 page.

Comment: Not if you use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` or handle the redirects. Wheres the curl code in your question?

Comment: Thanks @Loz, I've tried setting curl location with 'curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);' but by using this the page can not open since I'm using a class to open the page '$page = fopen($this->profile,"r");'

Answer (score 2):

Then try save `HTML` before `redirect`:

```
$new_url =  'www.example.com';
$path = 'C:/page.html';

// load and save the file
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($new_url);
$doc->saveHTMLFile($path);

// redirect to new pages
header('Location:'. $new_url);
exit();
```

Comment: If I save before redirection, I will be ask to input the authentication details every time.

Comment: Thanks Shail, but saving before redirecting the page will save only the 'The document has moved here' page and not the targeted HTML page.

Comment: can you post your `curl` code. because i just run the above code. it worked for me.

Comment: ' $direction = "http://example.com";
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "-");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $direction);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $new_url[$i]); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6) Gecko/2009011913 Firefox/3.0.6");
   
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $output;
 curl_close($ch);'